# How to create instance of Ckeditor 5 on already rendered html in angular 5?

Tags: angular-material, ckeditor5

I have used this solution https://github.com/mswilson4040/ckangular and it has solved my issue of ckeditor not working in angular. Here they are creating html first for editor on which its instance will be created and then you call ckedtor create function. Now I have case where I have a modal where html is rendered first and then i need to create ckeditor instance. I am using below code currently to achieve this:

```
//where editor instance will be created.
<span *ngIf="generate">
{{generateEditors()}}//calling type script function to create a instance on above

.ts:
generateEditors() {
debugger;
this.ckEditor = new CkEditor();
this.ckEditor.create('purpose-editor');
this.generate = false;
}
```

The problem in this function is it is calling again and again infinite calling and my app gets hang.

Seconfly I have installed ng-onload package but I dont know how to import and use that in
//where editor instance will be created.

So quick help in this either case will be appreciated.

Comment: waiting for reply on this. Any one.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't move the content of your span with the `*ngIf` into a component and initialize ckeditor on the `ngAfterViewInit` life-cycle hook of the component?